# If statement with OR always returning TRUE

Tags: conditionals, advanced-conditionals

I'm doing lots of checks against segments to try and perm redirect a very large list of old URLs and seem to have run into an issue with conditionals.

```
{if segment_1 == 'category' OR segment_1 == 'Category'}
```

Seems to always return true, even if segment_1 == 'sajdhjknsdjksad'. Is there a known bug, or am I doing something incredibly stupid?

**UPDATE**

The cause of the issue appears to be the redirect plugin I'm using getting evaluated before advanced conditionals, and then proceeding to redirect even if it shouldn't have actually been called. I'm using RedirectURL by Rodrigo Passos

Comment: Which version of EE are you using? Works for me in 253 and 255

Comment: Save yourself some heartache and prop up $20 for detour pro, 301 redirects in an instant

Comment: Using 2.4.0, have some extensive custom plugins that aren't playing nice with 2.5.x and the client isn't keen on paying me to spend lots of time sorting it out

Comment: Detour Pro is $22, works with 2.4 and you can add all redirects in literally minutes. If they're tight with $$, this is the smart move yeah ? Other then that, is there anything else going on in your template ?

Comment: Just done some quick testing, think I've found the issue.

The extension I'm using to make the redirect a 301 instead of a standard redirect is having it's template tag parsed before the conditional due to advanced conditionals doing crazy things for the template parsing order

Comment: Probably because all plugins get evaluated before conditionals kick in. A redirect plugin should really have taken this into account and use extension hooks to do the redirect *after* parsing has finished, but it sounds like that's not the case. For the record, it would be great if you can add the name of the plugin you're using to your original question to help others with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, it appears this isn't a problem with your conditionals. It's a problem with the RedirectURL extension redirecting users before your page has finished parsing.

Generally in EE, all plugins/tags are parsed before conditionals are applied. A plugin which drastically alters the response (such as performing a redirect) should take this into account, and use an extension hook and some cunning to perform the redirect only after the template finishes parsing.

In this particular case, it's probably easier to find a different plugin to handle your redirects.